# .NET Core service/daemon appsettings.json location (user folder or ProgramData)

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config

I have a Windows service that runs as a specific user (agent installed on desktop machines) - I had originally stored/updated `appsettings.json` in `Program Files` alongside the binary, but this causes issues during updates etc.

I have since moved to using an app config file under the users home directory - which I create manually ([Finding local users profile path in C# and creation of folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465669/finding-local-users-profile-path-in-c-sharp-and-creation-of-folder?noredirect=1#comment131456782_74465669)).

I also see there is a `ProgramData` enum that is available via [.NET directory enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0), and would save the above code (less things to break in future).

The Linux/MacOS version of this software would be under `/home/myuser` or `/etc/myapp`. I need to consider this as I write an abstraction layer to run my `BackgroundWorker` as a daemon and the associated installation thereof.

**My question** is which is better to follow for this multi-platform supported app, store config files by user directory, or program data directory?

Appreciate this is on the fringes of development question, but also not necessarily serverfault question - if better suited let me know and will repost on a different site.

Comment: I would suggest to containerize you app with .net 6. the world of docker containers is where you need to be :)

Comment: For any infra would agree, however this is for an agent installed on a user machine. I wouldnt want docker as a dependency.

Comment: It depends? Basically, is the expectation that the settings would be shared between users? If yes, then it should be in program data. If not, under the user's.

Comment: Very pertinent and succinct. Put as you have, the answer is no, no sharing. The service user would only have access to that data, no one else.